# Realizar distintas operaciones segun la opcion elegida de un select, en Javascript

Tags: javascript, select

tengo  un formulario con dos inputs donde se ingresarian los numeros y debajo un select con las opciones de las operaciones, segun lo seleccionado hay que realizar una operacion matematica distinta.Todo esto se realiza luego de un evento click que tiene el boton del formulario...El problema es que no se como obtener las opciones del select y si deberia usar un switch case o condicionales para realizar las operaciones segun lo seleccionado.

Comment: Puedes usar switch o condicionales. Cualquiera esta bien. El valor del select lo obtienes con la propiedad value del mismo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que si es un if o un switch es bastante irrelevante, son prácticamente lo mismo (para tu caso)

Yo te presento una solución totalmente distinta, basada en diccionario.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```js
const OperSelect = document.getElementById("operaciones");
const respuesta = document.getElementById("respuesta");

const Operaciones = {
   "Suma" : (a,b) => { return a+b },
   "Resta": (a,b) => { return a-b }
};

function Init(){
 Object.keys(Operaciones).forEach( el => {
   const opt = document.createElement("option");
   opt.value = el;
   opt.text = el;
   OperSelect.appendChild(opt);
 });
}

function calcular(valor1, valor2){
  respuesta.value = Operaciones[OperSelect.value]( Number( valor1), Number(valor2));
}

Init();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="valor1" />

<select id="operaciones"></select>
<input type="number" id="valor2" />

<button onclick="calcular(valor1.value,valor2.value)">CALCULAR</button>

<output id="respuesta"><output>
```

1. Primero tienes un objeto que tiene todas la operaciones, con el mismo formato puede agregar más quieras
2. Luego una función Init que inicializa el select con la cantidad de operaciones que tienes. Es decir, no necesitar cargar manualmente el select, esta función lo hará por ti
3. La función calcular que toma el valor del select, lo busca en Operaciones y realiza la función correspondiente a la operación matemática.

Entonces tú quieres agregar más operaciones. Solo añade más funciones en el objeto "Operaciones" no debes modificar nada más

Comment: Muy bien explicada la respuesta. Aunque no es buena práctica andar dando soluciones sin que se vea esfuerzo del OP. Saludos.